# How to open Auto Cad file in HTML 5

Tags: html

Can anyone tell me how to open **Auto CAD** file in HTML5?

Is this the same way we open any image in HTML or something different?

I think the extension of Auto Cad file is `.dwg`.

I am new to HTML5.

Comment: You simply AJAX the CSS3 with your SOAP. Seriously though, what gave you the idea that you could do anything of the sort?

Comment: @zzzzBov, there are browser plugins for viewing AutoCAD files, may be what he's thinking of. My company has used them in the past, bit I can't remember where to find them, right now.

Comment: Hi Michael and zzzzBov, Thanks for your reply,
@ MIchael - I don't find any plug-in which could run AutoCAD file :-( 
@ zzzzBov - I couldn't get your point how can i do this in J2EE, Can you please give me some more idea. that would be great help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML5 does not support the auto cad file format. You should look into exporting your data to **webgl** which is supported by HTML5.

Comment: Thanks tnt, i did some R&D on this and did not find any solution yet. thanks for reply.